# How to replace a value at an index of a comma delimited string?

Tags: .net, vb.net

How do I replace a value at a specific column in a comma delimited file, based on the header row?  I don't want to use a .Replace, because it will replace all the data it finds and any string function that finds the first occurrence of can find the wrong occurrence.

The header row of the comma delimited file:
File Name, Owner, Species, Age, Column n

And I need to change the species in row index 2 of the file from Cat to Dog.  I can't do a simple find and replace because and owner's name or file name could contain the string Cat. For instance, Catherine.

Example file:

```
File Name, Owner, Species, Age, Column n
C:\SomeFileName\, Catherine, Cat, 4, Caterpillar
C:\CatsAndDogs, CatterShark, Cat, 5, Foo
```

I know Species is at column index 2.

I'm trying to loop through the text file and do something like this:

```
If MyTextFile(m).Split(",")(2) = "Cat" Then
    MyTextFile(m).Split(",")(2) = "Dog"
End If
```

The file would look like:

```
File Name, Owner, Species, Age, Column n
C:\SomeFileName\, Catherine, Cat, 4, Caterpillar
C:\CatsAndDogs\, CatterShark, Cat, 5, Foo
```

---

Answer based on the answer from ChrisF - Convert the rows to lists to get indexes and replace values at indexes, convert back to comma delimited string.  See below.

```
Dim MyFileAsListOfRows As List(Of String) = IO.File.ReadAllLines(PathAndFileName).ToList()
Dim delimiter As String = ","

' Read the first line into a header row into a list
Dim headerRow As List(Of String) = MyFileAsListOfRows(0).Split(delimiter).ToList()
Dim idxSpecies As Int16 = headerRow.IndexOf("""Species""")


Dim originalText As String = "Cat"
Dim newText As String = "Dog"

For m As Integer = 0 To MyFileAsListOfRows.Count() - 1

    Dim currentRecord As List(Of String) = MyFileAsListOfRows(m).Split(delimiter).ToList()

    If CurrentRowInLoop(indexOfSpecies) = originalText Then
        CurrentRowInLoop(indexOfSpecies) = newText
    End If

    ' Use String.Join to convert the list of values in this row back to a comma delimited string and replace the old string with the new string.
    MyFileAsListOfRows(m) = String.Join(delimiter, CurrentRowInLoop)

Next

' Write all lines to file
IO.File.WriteAllLines(PathAndFileName, MyFileAsListOfRows)
```

Comment: You want to replace the first occurence of Cat with Dog?

Comment: There's a header row that defines each column, so I have to find the index of the column I'm looking for and replace text at that index.  I guess I can do it in a datatable, but I'm trying to avoid reading delimited file into a table then converting back to delimited string to write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to split the text, replace the first occurrence of "Cat" and then rejoin the text into the output string:

```
var words = MyTextFile(m).Split(",")
if words(1) = "Cat" then
    words(1) = "Dog"
end if

var result = String.Join(",", words)
```

*syntax may be a little funky as I'm not used to writing VB.NET off the top of my head*

Comment: Correct. I'll add the edited version of this to my question then you can copy it to this accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use IndexOf to find the first occurence of Cat and then use Substring to rebuild the string using the two parts before and after the position

```
Dim idx = MyTextFile(m).IndexOf("Cat")
if idx <> -1 Then
    MyTextFile(m) = MyTextFile(m).Substring(0, idx) & "Dog" & _
                    MyTextFile(m).Substring(idx+3)
End If
```

Comment: Clever, thanks.  I updated the last line so it can handle dynamic string lengh. MyTextFile(m).Substring(idx+originalText.Length)

Comment: Yes that's the right thing to do in production code.

Comment: Eh, I just realized this finds the first occurrence of. If Species is the 3rd column, and the first column is FileName with Cat in the name it'll change the pointer to the file without changing the name of the file.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand

Comment: Sorry, my phrasing is bad. I'll update the question to describe that I'm looking for the index of a column based off the header row. I.E. is Species is the 3rd column then I need to replace the text in the 3rd position of the delimited file. Columns 1 or 2 could contain the species.

Comment: Well, now it is a lot more clearer but now my answer is totally wrong. The answer from @CrhrisF below is correct